# React transfer data through components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux

I have parent component and child(listView) component. My target is to send backend dispatched data from parent to child. I achieve that via button click. Problem is that child renders after second parent button click. Maybe my mistake is somewhere in `componentWillReceiveProps`?

**Parent:**

```
class Parent extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            dataSource: '',
            noRepos: false
        };
    }

    componentWillReceiveProps(newProps) {
        this.setState({
            dataSource: newProps.data
        });
        this.validateData(newProps)
    }
    submitUsername() {
        if(this.validateInput()){
            this.props.dispatch({type: 'DUMMY', state: this.state.username});
        } else {
            this.setState({emptyInput: true});
        }
    }
    render() {
        return (
            ...
            <View>
                <ListViewComponent dataRecieved={this.state.dataSource} />
            </View>
            ...
        );
    }
}

export default connect(state => {
    return {
        data: state.data,
    };
})(Parent);
```

**Child:**

```
export default class ListViewComponent extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            dataSource: new ListView.DataSource({
                rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2,
            }),
        };
    }

    propTypes: {
        dataRecieved: PropTypes.func.string
    };

    componentWillReceiveProps(newProps) {
        this.setState({
            dataSource: this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(this.props.dataRecieved),
        });
    }
    renderRow(rowData) {
        return (
            <View>
                <Text>{rowData.name}</Text>
            </View>
        );
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                <ListView dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
                          enableEmptySections={true}
                          renderRow={this.renderRow} />
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: The error is that your `ListViewComponent`'s `componentWillReceiveProps` is using `this.props.dataReceived` instead of `newProps.dataReceived`. Also please check your spelling, it should be `Received`, not `Recieved`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, a general advice is to always keep a single source of truth:

- do not copy the data that you already have in props to your internal component state. Use the data in props.
- try to create your components as stateless as possible (see above...use props, or have the component listen to a 'store'. See Redux or AltJs).

---

Specifically to try to solve your issue:

In parent replace:

```
  <ListViewComponent dataRecieved={this.state.dataSource} />
```

with

```
  <ListViewComponent dataRecieved={this.props.data} />
```

And in ListViewComponent, don't do:

```
    this.setState({
        dataSource: this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(this.props.dataRecieved),
    });
```

but do:

```
render() {

    var ds = new ListView.DataSource({
                    rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2,
    })
    , dataSource = ds.cloneWithRows(this.props.dataRecieved);

    return (
        <View>
                <ListView dataSource={dataSource}
            enableEmptySections={true}
            renderRow={this.renderRow} />
        </View>
    );
}
```

The above is untested code, but should serve as a guide to what approach to follow.

Comment: 1. Where you see data copy? 2 Give example. You see this is not an answer. This is some guidelines

Comment: I thought it was obvious where the data was being copied. I.E in `Parent` this.setState({ dataSource: newProps.data })

Comment: Is this copy or reference?

Comment: It's cloning the data in props into the state.

Comment: How to avoid that?

Comment: You should not be re-creating the data source inside render. `Parent` should be passing a new data source to `ListViewComponent`.

Comment: Is it good practice to pass global variable instead of state?

Comment: @TeodorKolev, look at my answer. And no, never pass a global.

Answer (score 1):

The way you originally implemented `ListViewComponent` is fine, and you SHOULD be using `componentWillReceiveProps` when refreshing your `ListView`. Every best practice out there says to do this (just Google `react native redux listview`). You just have a slight error in your implementation that I mentioned in a comment above. Also, you *should not* be recreating the `ListView.DataSource` inside the `render` function, that is not good for performance and defeats the purpose of `rowHasChanged` in `ListView.DataSource`.

The  error that I'm talking about is here:

```
componentWillReceiveProps(newProps) {
  this.setState({
    dataSource: this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(this.props.dataRecieved),
  });
}
```

it should be:

```
// ListViewComponent
componentWillReceiveProps(newProps) {
  this.setState({
    dataSource: this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(newProps.dataRecieved),
  });
}
```

Also, your `Parent` should not be holding a `dataSource` in its `state`, just pass `data` straight down to `ListViewComponent` because Redux is passing it as a `prop` already:

```
class Parent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      // ...
    };
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(newProps) {
    // ...
  }

  submitUsername() {
    if (this.validateInput()) {
      this.props.dispatch({ type: 'DUMMY', ... });
    } else {
      // ...
    }
  }
  render() {
    return (
      ...
      <View>
        {/* this.props.data automatically comes from the `connect` wrapper below */}
        <ListViewComponent dataRecieved={this.props.data} />
      </View>
      ...
    );
  }
}

export default connect(state => {
  return {
    data: state.data,
  };
})(Parent);
```

You should also take a look at this [gist](https://gist.github.com/christopherdro/89bc57a19ff02f061954). It is an example of how to use Redux alongside a `ListView`. His example uses `cloneWithRowsAndSections`, but because you don't have sections, you just adapt with `cloneWithRows` instead. This gist was written by a pretty active core React Native developer.